# How to create barcodes and QRcodes in .NET 6 without System.Drawing.Common?

Tags: .net, barcode, .net-6.0

I have been using ZXing.Net to create barcodes and QRcodes for several years.  However, it depends on (more accurately, my implementation of the actual rendering to a BMP depends on) System.Drawing.Common which as of .NET 6.0 is only compatible with windows.  As such I can no longer use this library in my .NET 6.0 app when it is hosted in a Docker Linux container.

I have tried to create an image from the ZXing PixelData using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics but have had no luck - the lack of Microsoft.Maui.Graphics documentation at this point doesn't help.

Any ideas on how to create bar codes and QR codes in .NET 6 with using System.Drawing.Common?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only

Comment: Thanks for the info - this gives me a temporary workaround.  However, I'd rather have a way forward that does not depend on System.Drawing.Common.

Comment: You have to read the entire article, it gives specific library alternatives to drop the dependency.

Comment: I did - I'd rather be using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics rather than a third party library, but there is so little documentation for this library (as I said in the question) that I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @ProfNimrod `rather than a third party library,` what is ZXing then? And why is using an unreleased, still experimental library *not* built for this purpose any better than using one of the popular, well-maintained purpose-built alternatives? `the lack of Microsoft.Maui.Graphics documentation at this point` exactly. Because it's not finished and not meant to be used by application developers yet. Never mind that you'd be adding a huge dependency (MAUI) just to use a single class

Comment: I'm talking about the the actual rendering of the BMP.  I'd rather be using the .NET 6 equivalent of System.Drawing.Common.  If Microsoft provided a bar code library I'd rather use that too but they don't as far as I know.

Comment: Again, why? I suspect you misunderstand what System.Drawing.Common was for - it wasn't buit to generate images but display them using Windows' GDI+ API. Even that is obsolete and too slow now. The equivalent MAUI library will be used to display images too, not generate them. Never mind that it *won't* work on WebAssembly. Developers used `System.Drawing` for image processing gratuitously but it was simply too restricted for this. That's why even in .NET Old people are using ImageSharp and Skia instead

Comment: OK - makes sense.  I'll check out these other libraries.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I've just finished a rewrite using ImageSharp and the code is far cleaner than it was with system.drawing.  Many thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`However, it depends on System.Drawing.Common` that's not correct. ZXing can work with multiple libraries by using the correct binding package. NuGet contains [13 different binding packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=zxing.net.bindings) including [ZXing.Net.Bindings.ImageSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.ImageSharp/0.16.9-beta) and  [ZXing.Net.Bindings.SkiaSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.SkiaSharp/) and

If you check [the source code repo in Github](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/tree/master/Source/Bindings) you'll see that the bindings to OpenCVSharp, ImageSharp, SkiaSharp, EtoForms and Windows are kept up to date

Comment: Thanks - I should have said "my implementation" depends on system.drawing.common.  I'll take a look at these other bindings, but I'd rather still use an MS library for the rendering - whatever the cross-platform equivalent of system.drawing.common is going to be.  At this point I assume it's going to be Microsoft.Maui.Graphics, but maybe not.